# Unable to start camel cxf 2.15.1 in Websphere 7.0

Tags: apache-camel, websphere, cxf, websphere-7

I am using camel 2.15.1 which uses CXF 3.0.4. I am trying to deploy my web application into Websphere 7.0. It is throwing Incompatible class version version. I have already Disabled websphere JAX WS engine com.ibm.websphere.webservices.DisableIBMJAXWSEngine=true and changed classloader to parent last. Still get below error. Similar approach with Camel 2.10.X on my earlier application has worked though. Below is stacktrace.

```
[5/11/16 21:12:59:157 GMT+08:00] 00000024 extension     E com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor createServletWrapper Error occured while preparing the servlet for initialization.
                                 javax.servlet.ServletException: SRVE0207E: Uncaught initialization exception created by servlet
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:434)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:169)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1809)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:98)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:1038)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:959)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:638)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:304)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:166)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:731)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:616)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:376)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1147)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1320)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:611)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:945)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:760)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1292)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5305)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5483)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1297)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2069)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:434)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:377)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:648)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:610)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1152)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
        at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
        at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1146)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:999)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1331)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1224)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:242)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:353)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:595)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionException: Could not load extension class org.apache.camel.component.cxf.transport.CamelTransportFactory.
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:183)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.getClassObject(Extension.java:199)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerImpl.activateAllByType(ExtensionManagerImpl.java:144)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:180)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.ExtensionManagerBus.<init>(ExtensionManagerBus.java:186)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:40)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:36)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.createBus(CXFBusFactory.java:32)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:146)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:94)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:83)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:83)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:76)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:358)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: JVMCFRE003 bad major version; class=org/apache/camel/component/cxf/transport/CamelTransportFactory, offset=6
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:287)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:74)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:778)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.localFindClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:691)
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:532)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.extension.Extension.tryClass(Extension.java:164)
        ... 78 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It is due to WAS 7.0 running with java 6 and application is build using 1.7.